# Change the from address when forwarding a message in Gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, email-forwarding

Normally when you setup Gmail to forward a message via a filter, the from address will not be changed from the originating email. This is different than a manual forward which will quote the forwarded message and change the from address to your current email address.

Is there any way to have Gmail automatically forward email but also show the sender as being the account that is forwarding the email instead of the originating email address.

I know that I can set up a temporary POP account which reads these messages and then forwards them, the problem with this method is that the POP access is not instantaneous.

If this is not possible in Gmail, are there any alternatives?

Here's an example:

Say you have A send an email to B which forwards it to C (A > B > C). C will see that the message came from A (A > C). I would like it to appear that it's coming from B (B > C).

I don't mind that the headers may contain information which reveals that the message originated from A. I only care that the "from" field shows B instead of A.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this issue using an App Script that scans the inbox every 10 min.

Needed it to automate expense report forwarding.

Solution and code: https://github.com/emreberge/gmail-email-forwarding

Answer (score 0):

Set "B" as your default "Send mail as" option inside Gmail settings. Then, there is an option for "When receiving a message" and select the second option "Always reply from the default address".